# How to deploy hourly scheduled job and daily scheduled job into UAT and Production

Tags: deployment

i am scheduling hourly one class by using

```
PortalUserDisableBatch pudbatch = new PortalUserDisableBatch();

String CRON_EXP = '0 0 * * * ?';

System.schedule('Hourly', CRON_EXP, pudbatch );
```

i need to move it into UAT and Production. Do i need to do same in UAT and Production or is there any way to deploy like creating change sets

Answer (score 1):

System.Schedule is a static method for system operations which belongs to System Class. You can't include a system method command in a change set. For more information on [System Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)

You can implement a schedulable class to schedule your batch class. This class can be included in a change set.

```
global class SchedularForBatchApex implements Schedulable {

        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
            myBatchClass d = new myBatchClass();
              database.executebatch(d, 10);
        }

         Public static void SchedulerMethod(){
             SchedularForBatchApex s = new SchedularForBatchApex();
             String cron_exp = '0 59 * * * *';
             System.schedule('myBatchClass', cron_exp, s);
         }

 }
```

Comment: So, we need to run that schedule class in anonymous window for Production right?

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva yes, click Debug. Open Execute Anonymous Window to open the Enter Apex Code window. Enter the code you want to run in the Enter Apex Code window or click to open the code editor in a new browser window. To automatically open the resulting debug log when execution is complete, select Open Log.

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva Did it help ? If yes accept the answer so that it's helpful for others who would have a similar question

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva one extra bit -- when you use DC in PROD, be sure to log in as the user you want to be the running user for the schedulable class. This improves traceability a lot as any updates done by the schedulable class can be traced back to the desired intent rather than some random sysad

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to execute post-deployment scripts in salesforce to execute scripts after deployment.

But, If you have a CI/CD pipeline in place for the deployment.. we can use [apex execute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm)

```
sfdx force:apex:execute
```

and the apex class can just contain anonymous script using

```
ExecuteAnonymousResult executeAnonymous(String code)
```

This is like running an Execute Anonymous operation so, it is subject to all of the [usual transaction limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm).